# Mutithreading a method from an object instantiated in the main thread

Tags: python, oop, threadpool, python-multithreading

If I instantiate an object in the main thread, and then send one of it's member methods to a ThreadPoolExecutor, does Python somehow create a copy-by-value of the object and sends it to the subthread, so that the objects member method will have access to its own copy of `self`?

Or is it indeed accessing `self` from the object in the main thread, thus meaning that every member in a subthread is modifying / overwriting the same properties (living in the main thread)?

Answer (score 0):

Threads share a memory space.  There is no magic going on behind the scenes, so code in different threads accesses the same objects.  Thread switches can occur at any time, although most simple Python operations are atomic.  It is up to you to avoid race conditions.  Normal Python scoping rules apply.

You might want to read about ThreadLocal variables if you want to find out about workarounds to the default behavior.

Processes as quite different.  Each Process has its own memory space and its own copy of all the objects it references.